# Can iframe be safely used to display content from the same application that houses it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iframe

If content is hosted in an iframe within an existing application ONLY using relative URLs from the same host using the same HTTPS protocol.

To what degree can it be considered safe?

CORS does not apply, correct?

The iframe can be defined with **Same Site** & **Secure**, correct?

What other iframe specific security concerns need to be considered?

Comment: The question is, why would you need to use Iframes to display content from the same source?

Comment: So the deployed application is MVC and this approach would be used to incrementally replace Razor Views with a different technology stack. Imagine a page that is composed of 4 Partial Razor Views, this pattern would replace the partial HTML of a particular View with an iframe that points to a relative path within the same deployed MVC application. Pls do not be concerned with what tech stack or the styling/look & feel. These concerns have already been proven and are non-issues for us... This post is specifically asking about this usage of an iframe, in general. Thank you for time and feedback.